# How to add view to node (drupal 8)

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I have create view with custom type "banner".
And I have node with custom type "product".
The product node have page. /product-1
How to link the banner view to product node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as admin account to Drupal
got to the page

> /admin/structure/block

Find your view at bottom (if you create view block)

> Click on Configure

See the section **Visibility**
Select tab **Pages**
**Show for the listed pages** option is already selected you can change this as per your needs
Now put your URL into the textarea like
if you want your view should display only on a single page put your full URL in this textarea like

> product-1

but if you want your block should display on all page which has URL like product-1, product-2, product-3 and so on you can put your URL with wildcard entry like

> product-*

Now your views block should display on all pages starting URL with product- not matter what is after product- your views block will display on all pages
I hope you get some points of action to achieve you needs
Thanks